# Android AssetManager Timeout Exception

Tags: android, timeoutexception, android-assetmanager

We have recently started experiencing a lot of AssetManager Timeout Exception.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
   at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.close(AssetManager.java:565)
   at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.finalize(AssetManager.java:598)
   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

We recently updated support lib version to 27.1.1 , playservices to '11.0.4'.
Can't think of any possible reason for the crash appearing recently in large numbers.

Comment: Still have this problem to this day. No idea what causes it. Did you ever find a solution?